# How to take screen shots in windows system using Intersystems Cache?

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems, mumps

How to take screen shots in windows system using inter systems cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache doesn't have any built-in way to directly take a screen shot, so the closest you could come is to have a Caché process call something that *does* know how to take a screen shot.  The ways to call out from cache are documented [on the Intersystems web site](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20131/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCIO_callout) and this same documentation is usually included in a Caché install.

The simplest option (and you don't give enough information to know whether that will work) is probably to call something like $zf(-1,"import -window root screen.jpeg").  In this example, "import -window root screen.jpeg" is a command-line call.  $zf(-1) spawns a child process and runs whatever text you give in the second parameter as a command-line call.

I got the specific text for this call from [a question on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/75614/take-a-screen-shot-from-command-line-in-windows), which you might want to look at if you don't have a screen shot program available that can be called from the command prompt.

If that doesn't work for you, there are other options than $zf(-1) available, but you will probably need to read the linked documentation to decide what works best.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible. InterSystems Cache is DataBase, you have to use any other languages for it.