# how to call a simple java program from intersystems cache?

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems, mumps

I have seen the document of inter-systems cache describes calling other programming functions like c,Java.
could any one help me to understand the way of doing it with simple Java example.

Comment: This really has the same answer as your recent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806060/how-to-take-screen-shots-in-windows-system-using-intersystems-cache

Answer (score 1):

For simple calling other programms from InterSystems Cache, you could use [$zf(-1)](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20131/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RCOS_fzf-1#RCOS_B70652) function.
For example:

```
s sc=$zf(-1,"java -jar mysimple.jar")
```

But you have to know, that, calling interactive and other applications which must connect with user or with his desktop, who working in server where stand Cache, it is a bad way. And you have to use only console applications.